# How to make objects inside a rectangle NOT move in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a rectangle and its background image is a screenshot of a form.

I have placed many Gauge Panels on this rectangle where check marks need to be.

Based on certain logic, the Gauge Panel will be visible or not.

The problem is that if all Gauge Panels on the left side are hidden, it moves all the Gauge Panels on the right side.

Here's a screenshot during design mode:

[image]

And here's when I run it:

[image]

I'm assuming it has moved because there was no visible "Yes" check mark.

How should I go about making sure these panels are FIXED inside the rectangle?

EDIT -

I tried putting the items inside rectangles and I'm running into the same problem:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your gauges inside fixed rectangles so even when they're not visible, their container rectangles will still take up space in your report on the left side and not interfere with the checks on the right hand side.

My general rule of thumb when trying to do fixed layouts in SSRS is use a lot of rectangles, as they are rendered as absolute DIVs and therefore bend to your whim a bit more in terms of heights, widths, and positioning.

Comment: So you're saying to put each gauge in a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, that way even when the gauge itself is invisible, the rectangle still takes up the same space.

Comment: Thanks bro! I'm trying it now. Will accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: Kyle, I put each gauge inside a rectangle of exactly the same size as the gauge but I'm still having problems. I'm editing my main post with some screenshots

Comment: Even with your screenshots, it's hard to tell exactly what's happening, but again, go back to the general rule of thumb: if you want something to take up space even if it's not there, put it in a fixed rectangle. So you may need it for all your check marks / gauges, etc, if you don't want them to grow/shrink/consume each other when they're not visible or empty.

Comment: I got it. I basically made the rectangles a little larger to make up for the "blank" areas. thanks again!